# Conditional while loop does not react properly

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to write a while loop with the logic as follows:

```
while enemy is alive and characters are alive:
    continue...
```

However each character's health is bound to an individual variable/list entry.

So I have:

```
while enemydata[2] >0 and combatpartystats[0][1] >0 and combatpartystats[1][1] >0 and combatpartystats[2][1] >0 and combatpartystats[3][1] >0:
    continue...
```

Yet the loop breaks when any of the four character's health goes below 0.

I only want the loop to break when all characters are dead or when the enemy is dead.

I hope I've explained my problem well enough, any questions just ask.

Comment: Use `or` instead of `and` if you want the loop to continue if either condition is true.  Remember, `and` is true if both operands are true, and `or` is true if either operand is true.  You should be able to reason it out from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. Try this:

```
while enemydata[2] > 0 and (combatpartystats[0][1] > 0 or combatpartystats[1][1] > 0 or combatpartystats[2][1] > 0 or combatpartystats[3][1] > 0):
    continue...
```

This will break only if your enemy is dead or all teammates are dead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
while enemydata[2] >0 and combatpartystats[0][1] >0 and combatpartystats[1][1] >0 and combatpartystats[2][1] >0 and combatpartystats[3][1] >0:
```

where it will continue only as long as all of the above are true, change the "and" statements to "or" statements and then if any of them evaluate to true the script will continue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your **ands** to **ors** and I think it will do what you want.